# When pasting the same value into Input field, on second time pasting two-way data binding doesn't work

Tags: angular, input, angular2-ngmodel

I have the following input tag:

```
<input type="number" [ngModel]="position" (ngModelChange)="onChangePosition($event)" />
```

`onChangePosition` function mainly checks the length of the input value, if the length is more than 3 it cuts and leaves only 3 numbers.
When I paste long numbers like *12345*, the first time it cuts and sets *123* to `position` property and that is reflected on the view.
But when pasting the same value over old one on second time, `position` changes as before but not reflected on the view.

You can see this behavior in
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ht9gmk)

Copy value **12345** and paste it into the field, you will see **123**. Correct result.
Then paste value into field again, you will see that position is changed but inside input field it stays as it is. Unwanted result.

Appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage the gap between what your input and what is in ngModel with (input) event:

```
<input type="number" #myPosition
       [ngModel]="position"
       (input)="myPosition.value = position"
       (ngModelChange)="onChangePosition($event)" />
```

Here I used the template variable and its value

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tgkcqg)

Comment: Thank you Vega. I see you returning position on onChangePosition, is it necessary? I tried without it and worked as well. Actually initially I was using input event for onChangePosition but then I also needed to handle keydown event as well. I wanted simplify this behavior as much as possible. It is possible to make that works properly without handling additional events? I don't understand what causes the issue. The binding doesn't work properly with input element?

Comment: return position was a reminiscent from a trial, of course you don't need it. I deleted it. It was supposed to work that way, the input and the boundd property have that gap because you change it programmatically

Comment: Are there better implementation for particular case? Because I don't understand why there are such kind of gap. Why Angular doesn't handle that gap? Why it works first time and not afterwards?

Comment: The change you make via the keyboard input will not interfere with model change. That is intended by the Angular design. But I am not responsible for that design, I can only help you fix it, that's what I did